# Power button doesn't turn on the laptop on first attempt

Tags: laptop, boot, bios, power

I have Dell 1764 for about 2 and half years and just recently power button start creating problem when I try to turn it on (it happened like over a night when i turned it off very fine and next day problem started. I can't even think a reason why it happened, it never dropped off or got anything spilled on it etc). Now I have to press power button few times, then it works. Sometime it starts PC on second or third attempt but sometimes I have to press it like tens of times to make it work. But yes, it does work in the end.

I get my laptop to repair shop and they fix it in few hours and got decent money but it work fine for about a week or two and then same problem started again (without any specific reason). Now they're saying it's related to BIOS and we have to find similar BIOS chip to fix it. Now it's been few weeks and still no good news.

So can anyone help, is it related to BIOS or it can be some other problem and any good tip about what to do to get it fix?

Comment: Ask the guy in the repair shop what exactly did he do that made this issue disappear for some time.

Comment: He said, i cleaned up the dust on button and board and that was the issue but now he's saying it's bios.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Mine is Dell vostro 3568. I had to press power button multiple times to make it start. LED blinks few times and then laptop actually starts.

Comment: Reseat (unplug, brush connectors, plug in again) the memory and the hard disk. Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Most power buttons simply cause two pieces of metal to touch when you press the button. This completes a circuit which signals the power supply to turn on the rest of the computer.

If something is blocking the connection between the pieces of metal under the power button, it could be struggling to complete the circuit. Or, if one of the wires going from the power button to the power supply is loose or has a bad connection somewhere, the same thing could result.

If you press the power button kind of hard and wiggle your finger a bit for a couple of seconds, does it work better on the first try? If yes, then it is probably related to the power button itself. If this doesn't seem to help, try slightly squeezing the laptop (top and bottom) near where the power cord plugs in, and while doing that press the power button. If this helps, then the problem is probably closer to the power supply rather than the button.

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution (Win.10)..

Control Panel>Power Options>...top left "choose what the power buttons do">change settings that are currently available>...then UN-check "Turn on Fast Startup".

Shut down and re start....problem should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Got a solution for this:

- Remove the AC adapter and battery, press and hold the power button for 40-60 seconds.
- Connect only the AC adapter, switch on the laptop.
- Then shut down and restart the system along with the battery.

It worked for me.

Comment: What is the root cause of the issue? Does the laptop go into Safe mode or Sleep mode or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers cover pretty much most of the known solutions for this problem.

An additional possibility is that the power button might have gotten worn out
and it takes some time before it recognizes a press.
To test this idea, open the computer while it is turned off, unplug the power button
from the motherboard and bridge the two pins where it was connected
using a screw-driver or anything that is conductive.
If the computer turns on immediately, then the power button needs replacement.
You might be able to get a new one from the manufacturer or from other avenues.

Another possibility is that the Power Supply Unit (PSU) is getting weak and
has difficulties to supply enough power to boot the computer.
Booting is one of the cases where more power is required to spin up or
otherwise start up in parallel all the connected devices.
A weak PSU will need replacement.

The last solution is to have a professional repairman examine the computer.
He will have the tools to analyze the problem, and the spare parts to test
his ideas. He might also give the computer a thorough cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

I've repaired these laptops for this issue many times...

The plastic frame backing of the power button is messed up so its not meeting the membrane correctly, even though it seems/feels like it is.

Personally, I would just open up the laptop, 
tear out the button
and just turn it on with a pencil eraser.

Why dont I suggest "replacing the button" you may ask?

Well you could do that, But its going to break again...
Thats why I dont warranty those buttons, because I know they WILL break again.
Just really crap design.

Literally just removing the button is easier, because when that button goes, you can't meet the switch without opening it again, however, more often than not... you can find a pen, pencil or elsewise "non-conductive poking implement" near by

Answer (score 0):

For me i have to hold the power button to turn the pc on when the option Fast Startup is on
But if i turn fast startup of only one click turns my pc on
I suggest you try turning it off or if it's already off try turning it on
As the laptop's are configured with a specific power plan(which during updates may get messed)and in my case holding the power button is the expected way to turn it on as written in the hand book i got with my laptop but i can now just turn it on in a single click thanks to turning the option off
Also there are multiple more benefits you get with turning it off
If you don't have an ssd then i recommendation restarting your pc Every day instead of turning off fast startup (just a tip and have no relation to your question)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).